# Are there any significant/meaningful ultrapowers other than the hyperreals?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

I have recently begun reading about non-standard analysis. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) wikipedia article it is possible to construct an ultrapower $M^I/\mathcal{U}$ from any structure $M$ and index set $I$ with non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ and obtain a transfer principle for it. The hypernaturals, hyperreals, hypercomplexes, etc. are simply the result of choosing $M \in \{\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \ldots\}$ and $I = \mathbb{N}$.

I was wondering, are there any other significant, meaningful or otherwise interesting choices for $I$? For example is there anything new to be learned from choosing $I = \mathbb{R}$ instead? It seems to me that such a set would be interesting since its elements are essentially equivalence classes of real functions instead of real sequences, yet I couldn't find any mention of such a set online.

Comment: For nonstandard analysis specifically it is very rare that one ever needs something more than merely a hyperreal field - that is, a non-Archimedean ordered field (+ lots of additional structure) which is an elementary extension of $\mathbb{R}$ (with all that extra structure). In those cases we just go with the simplest index set, because why not. In general model theory though we definitely look at larger index sets.